# gulp watching single file triggers on folder contents

Tags: gulp, watch

I have gulp task watching single file. And I want this watcher emit events when **only** this file changes, not files around it.

```
gulp.task('watchConfig', function(){
  var watcher = gulp.watch(['profiles.json'], ['updateConfig']);
  watcher.on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type);
  });
});
```

This watcher constantly triggers on `tmp` directory located at same level as `profile.json`. I get the following message

> File f:\*my_working_dir*\tmp\ was added

How can I make this task to trigger when **only** `profile.json` changes?

---

It seems that only *folders* trigger extra events, not regular files. Adding/deleting/renaming any folder at same level as `profile.json` triggers watcher, but this doesn't happen with other files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is how you are declaring which file to watch. 
Instead of:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch(['profiles.json'], ['updateConfig']);
```

try doing this:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('profiles.json', ['updateConfig']);
```

Anything inside of brackets should be a task that is to be run.

Comment: produces same result

Comment: I feel like we are missing a piece to this puzzle. Your code otherwise is sound. Have you tried tacking the directory onto the `profiles.json` portion? e.g.  `somedir/profiles.json`

Comment: Yes, and it works as quick fix. If `profiles.json` is isolated in its own folder, everything works perfect, but I would like to keep that file at top level.